# Como juntar colunas de um mesmo dataframe para criar outra coluna, no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quero juntar as colunas "Cep", "Rua", "Numero" e "Complemento", para criar a coluna "Endereço", sem apagar as colunas usadas.